# How to change the color of Preprocessor Conditionals such as #if in Vistual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, c-preprocessor, syntax-highlighting, atmelstudio

Is there a method to change the color of  **Preprocessor Conditionals** such as,

```
#if
#ifdef
#ifndef
#endif
```

I do work on large C libraries which use plenty of  Preprocessor Conditionals and as you can see in the example below, this really limits the readability of the code as C programmers conventionally do not indent these conditionals. 
Graying out these lines using Keywork Highlighting would be a big help on not confusing these un-indented lines as the end of long `if` statements etc.

Example code,

```
    ...
   if( ... )
    {

        for( uint8_t i = 0, k = 0; i < FOO; i += 16, k++ )
        {
            for( uint8_t j = 0; j < 16; j++ )
            {
#if defined( BAZ ) || defined( BAR )
                if( ... )
#else
                if( ... )
#endif
                {
                    if( ... )
                    { 
                        continue;
                    }
#if defined( BAZ_ ) || defined( BAR_ ) || defined( FOO_ )
                    if( ... )
                    {
                        if( ... )
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
#endif
                    if( ... ) 
                    { 
                        continue;
                    }
                    if( ... )
                    { 
                        foo++;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

Note: I have phrased the question for *Visual Studio*, however, I will be using the solution in ***Atmel Studio*** which is basically a re-badged version of the same software. I have successfully install most of the VS add-ons to Atmel Studio in the past but tbh I haven't given a R# a go, if your solution is going to include it.

### Update:

After posting the question I actually noticed the Syntax Highlighting on **Stackoverflow** does an amazing job doing exactly what I have in mind. The `#` conditions are grayed out and the rest of the code reads beautifully. I would like to be able to do the same on VS/AS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A year or two ago I ran across the solution: [Naggy](https://github.com/saaadhu/naggy). Among several other features (which I find useful), it grays out preprocessor conditionals just like you expect and want.

In Atmel Studio 7.0 it's available in the built-in Extensions Gallery. Install from there, restart AS, and you're good to go. There are no options or configuration settings; it's very simple, and works great.

I also had it working in Atmel Studio 6.2, but seems like I had to install it manually or something. [This AVR Freaks thread](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/new-extension-naggy) should help.

Comment: JBurger, this is absolutely fantastic and even better than what I had in mind. It actually dims the lines between the #defines which their argument isn't define. Legend. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Mehrad Certainly. I sometimes add a bunch of debugging code using different `#define` flags that I can quickly change and recompile. Some sections of code are almost unreadable without this extension, it's great.

Comment: JBurger, are there any settings for Naggy? I can't find any options or settings for it somehow.

Comment: @Mehrad nope, it's just enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio go to Tools/Options/Fonts and Colors and modify items *Preprocessor Keyword* and *Preprocessor Text*.

Comment: I only have a *Preprocessor Keyword* in my list and changing that didn't change anything in the `#ifdef` syntax. In fact I cannot even find what does it change.

Answer (score 4):

The feature in question in Visual Studio is called `Show Inactive Blocks.`  You can find the option in:

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> View`

.. or if using Visual Studio 2015 or newer, you can get there using the `Quick Launch` search bar (`Ctrl+Q`) and typing the word "Inactive".

This has been a core feature of Visual Studio since at least VS 2010.  The default setting is to dim inactive blocks of code at 65% opacity, which may not be enough to really stand out from other blocks of code on some monitors 
 (especially true if using the Dark themes).  I set mine to 45%.

Comment: To be honest, I mainly need this in Atmel Studio, which is almost a re- badged version of Visual Studio, but unfortunately I could not find the option you were mentioning. I also typed it in quick lunch and nothing came up. Thanks for the answer though. It 100% matches the question I asked here.